# Trim whitespace from icons

Tags: mfc, icons

I am working on an old MFC app.
The app uses some icons applied on buttons such as:

```
m_btnMyButton.SetIcon(IDI_ICON21, BS_CENTER, IDI_ICON21);
```

I wish to place the icons at the center of the buttons, however, the icons themselves are not centered. Basically they seem to be offset by random amounts. For example:[image] (I have added the black rectangles to show what I mean).

I know I can "trim" the whitespace off these icons/center these icons before compiling resources.(I know [ImageMagik](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#trim) can batch do this for me.) But I do not want to change the original icons on disk (may be used elsewhere).

What I want to do is maybe make a function in my code which does this trimming before applying the icon. That way I won't need to worry about any new or missed out icons.

Can anyone provide some insight about how I can "trim" the icons in my code?
Need to keep in mind that the offset for these icons is random, so I would need to find the offset to trim first.

Answer (score -1):

If you define the buttons as owner draw, you can place the icons anywhere you want when you render the button.

Comment: The OP is well aware, that the icon can be rendered anywhere. The question is, **where** they should be rendered, based on the image information alone.

Answer (score -1):

Create a function that do the following:

1. Create a `DC` of the size of the icon.
2. Fill the `DC` with the transparent color.
3. Draw the icon with `DrawIcon` api with the x/y offset that you want.
4. Create a new icon out of this bitmap.

Comment: I need to find the x/y offset, that is the issue.

Comment: @manimatters - You can visually decide the value of each icon and hard-code them in the function-call to create a new icon. Or if you want it to be automatic, you can scan the icon pixels for transparent color in the DC, in vertical/horizontal line format from each side, to detect the minimum bounding rectangle for the icon.

Comment: There is no such thing as *"the transparent color"*. An icon consists of two bitmaps: The image information and a mask. The mask controls, which areas of the image data should be rendered, and which areas should retain their previous color.